# Mysql Connection adapter error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I tried running db:migrate on my app and I'm getting this error.Not sure what is the cause.

- My database is MySQL
- using MySQL 64-bit connector
- ruby version:ruby 2.2.6p396 (2016-11-15 revision 56800) [i386-mingw32]
  I've done a google search and I'm not getting anything..Can anyone explain this error pls?

  NotImplementedError: NotImplementedError
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:85:in `exec_query'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:377:in 'select_prepared'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:39:in`select_all'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:95:in `select_all'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/querying.rb:39:in`find_by_sql'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:702:in `exec_queries'

  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/rake:23:in`load'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/rake:23:in `'
  Tasks: TOP => db:

migrate

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..

Check your `config/database.yml` file.

your `config/database.yml` must look like and `username`, `password` should be change your `mysql`'s `username`, `password`..

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: username
  password: password
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

development:
  <<: *default
  database: uBuild-rails_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: uBuild-rails_test


production:
  <<: *default
  database: uBuild-rails_development
  username: username
  password: password
```

Also check you `Gemfile`

```
gem 'mysql2', '< 0.3' # as stated above
```

Comment: my database.yml is similar but I'm still having the same issue              `development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
 # reconnect: false
  database: inventorydb_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: password
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, what I did was to create the project again using this command:

```
rails new my_project -d=mysql
```

This way the configuration in database.yml and gemfile is created automatically avoiding problems. You only need to edit database.yml mysql password after this you can use

```
rails g scaffold Examples attrib1:string attrib2:string
```

to create views etc

```
 rake db:create
```

to create the database and then

```
rake db:migrate
```

hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Database file is in config/database.yml and configuration be

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2 #if use postgres the add postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username : username #mysql username
  password : password #mysql password

development:
  <<: *default
  database: application_name

test:
  <<: *default
  database: application_name

production:
  <<: *default
  database: application_name
```

Run following command to setup database:

```
run rake db:create

run rake db:migrate
```